# How to make only specific user getting a newsletter-mail (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to implement a newsletter and added a choice field to my UserProfile class, to let users select if they want to get an newsletter or not:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    YES = 'YS'
    NO = 'NO'
    NEWS_CHOICES = (
        (YES, 'Yes'),
        (NO, 'No'),
    )
    newsletter = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices= NEWS_CHOICES, default=NO)
```

And I made this view to send a newsletter to the users, which want to get a newsletter (selected 'Yes'):

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser) 
def newsletter_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsletterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            reader = UserProfile.objects.filter(newsletter='YS')
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            subject = 'This is the Newsletter!'
            message = 'Hello!'
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_list = [reader.user.email]
            html_message = loader.render_to_string('gaestebuch/newsletter.html')
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_list, fail_silently = True, html_message=html_message)
            return redirect('gaestebuch:index')
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = NewsletterForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'gaestebuch/newsletter_form.html', context)
```

I am struggeling with :

```
to_list = [reader.user.email]
```

The error I am getting is:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I would be glad if someone could help me at this point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, `reader`, is a queryset, but you seem to be treating it as an single instance of `UserProfile`. This should work to add all the recipients to the list:

```
to_list = [r.user.email for r in reader]
```

Do note however the [following part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#send-mail)(emphasis mine):

> `recipient_list`: A list of strings, each an email address. **Each member of `recipient_list` will see the other recipients in the “To:” field of the email message.**

If you don't want all the recipients to see each other then you will need to send separate messages for each.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!